# Updating a scope property doesn't update the view

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

This is a question I've seen been asked many times before but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I have a simple code that updates a `loading` property and two divs, one that's supposed to be shown when loading is true and one that's shown when loading is false.

```
    $scope.loading = true;
    function getTasks() {
        $http.get(URL)
            .then(function (response) {
                //success
                $scope.tasks = response.data;
            }
            , function () {
                //failure
                $scope.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch tasks";
                $timeout(getTasks(), 5000); 
            })
            .finally(function () {
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
    <div ng-show="{{ loading === true }}">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-w-16 fa-spin fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="{{ loading === false }}">
```

However, even though `loading` does change to false, it doesn't update the view.

Some of the things I've tried are:

- Using the timeout service

  ```
              $timeout(() => {
                  $scope.loading = false;
              });
  ```
- Using `$scope.$apply()` both after changing loading to false and calling a function inside of apply.
- Adding the getTasks function to the scope.

Comment: As George alluded to, doing `loading === true` or `loading === false` will make your fellow devs laugh at you.  Use `loading` and `!loading`, the value is already true or false so all you're doing is slowing down you code by doing a redundant check

Comment: Also, unless you have a good reason for both divs to exist in your DOM at all times, you should use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div ng-show="{{ loading === true }}">` should be `<div ng-show="loading === true">` or just

```
<div ng-show="loading">
```

`loading` is a variable defined in your `scope`. And you can access scope variables as it is in your angular directives `ng-show` in your case